# Difference between "... view of being one of the..." and ...view of being like one of the..."

Tags: verbs

I can't understand the difference between the two following sentences:

> A very thoughtful view of being one of the locals.
>
> A very thoughtful view of being like one of the locals.

If both are right then please tell me the difference of meaning of these sentence?

Comment: Neither of those are complete sentences, so it's hard to tell.  Can you post the entire sentences?

Comment: @stangdon  I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

> being one of the locals

would usually be understood for a person who is part of a group (the locals)

> being *like* one of the locals

would usually be understood as a person not part of the group, who might be mistaken for being part of the group since they would appear to be from the group. Using "like" or "as" for comparison is called a **simile**.

> He was *like* a native New Yorker.
>   *He acted as if he was native to New York City.*

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following examples:

> He is a millionaire.
>
> He is *like* a millionaire.

The first sentence says he is a (relatively) wealthy man.  The second sentence says that, while he is not wealthy, he *seems*, in many ways, *like* a wealthy man.

In the same way your examples say either that the view is of the daily life of someone who *is* a local, or the daily life of someone who acts in a way that is *similar* to a local.